How to receive keyboard layout change event in Ubuntu in C
I'm working on a desktop application with GTK3 in C. I want to capture keyboard layout change events. I could not find any useful solutions online. The few solutions I found online were using infinite while loop to check for layout change, but I don't want to do that as I don't want one of my threads to wait forever.
Is there a way to receive keyboard layout change events over a signal mechanism?

This is specific to your desktop environment.  A solution that works for Gnome 3 may not work for others.

@stark, then  is there a way to get this event in c++
